# Tricky middle school pronoun case question

Tags: pronouns, demonstratives

My younger sister is reviewing for an upcoming exam using [quia](http://www.quia.com/pop/81942.html), which her teacher suggested.

She ran across the following question:

> Help me carry **_______** boxes into the house.

The options are 'those' and 'them.' The service indicates that the correct answer is 'them,' which is utterly baffling to me. I am not particularly great with grammar, but I don't think this can be right -- it is nearly painful to my ears.

**What is the correct answer? If it is 'them,' then what is the explanation.**

Comment: Like, what, were them boxes too heavy for one person to carry? :) . . . Then again, if them there boxes lie on the lawn too long, they tend to start walking themselves away, which ain't a good thing.

Comment: @F.E. Puh-leeze. In that register it's *lay*, not *lie*.

Answer (score 2):

The OED says that using *them* as a demonstrative adjective — as though it were modern *those* — is now considered passé:

> III. 5. As demonstr. adj. = **those**. Now only *dial*. or *illiterate*.

Therefore, under all reasonable scenarios, that was the wrong answer.